# Disabling Combobox with Leave event is selecting text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm using the Leave event on `Combobox` to disable it and load some data but, after leaving and disabling, it selects the whole text in `Combobox`. I want to unselect the text.

Im using:

```
cmbNome.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;    
cmbNome.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;    
cmbNome.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

if it helps...

the code:

```
    private void cmbNome_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbNome.Enabled = false;
        CarregarDados();
        CarregarTelefones();
    }
```

Comment: Try showing your Leave event code.  A disabled combobox shouldn't show any selection.

Comment: cmbNome.SelectionLength = 0; didnt work

Comment: I cannot duplicate your result.  Does it happen if you comment out the two Carregar functions?

Comment: Yes, it still happens. The two Carregar functions only fill other textboxes and listviews.

Comment: I cant post a picture to help, because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: As LarsTech said, disabled combos have no selection. Is the combo actually disabling?

Comment: Does the event even fire?  Do you have it wired up correctly?  Also, where in your code are you enabling the ComboBox?

Comment: I just figured out that the text is selected before Combobox is disabled, right after I press tab to choose the item on Combobox suggested source. How can I unselect before disabling?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting data source before disabling combo box:

```
        string[] data = new string[] {
            "Absecon","Abstracta","Abundantia","Academia","Acadiau","Acamas",
            "Ackerman","Ackley","Ackworth","Acomita","Aconcagua","Acton","Acushnet",
            "Acworth","Ada","Ada","Adair","Adairs","Adair","Adak","Adalberta","Adamkrafft",
            "Adams"

        };


        private void comboBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox2.DataSource = data;
            comboBox2.Enabled = false;
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

This code fills the combo with data; however, no item is selected and text field is empty

EDIT: added sample data

Answer (score 0):

Try to first deselect item and than set combobox disabled.

```
cmbNome.SelectedIndex = -1;
cmbNome.Enabled = false;
```